# how to ignore a specific subfolder in GitHub without removing the parent folder using .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working on a project in Git and I want to ignore a specific folder `./unit_testing/test_cache`. However, i need to keep `./unit_testing` folder itself. But When I push my code in GitHub this `./unit_testing` folder are removed in GitHub repository.

##### Directory Structure:

```bash
.

├── unit_testing 

│   └── test_cache

│       └── test_output.txt

└── test_project.py
```

##### .gitignore file:

```
/unit_testing/test_cache
```

I added a exclude pattern to my `.gitignore` file `!/unit_testing` However, the `./unit_testing` folder is still being removed from my repository when I push my code to GitHub.

##### Updated .gitignore File:

```
!/unit_testing
/unit_testing/test_cache
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't push an empty directory to git (and even if you are able to, you are not able to pull it down).
Edit: see this discussion: [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)